# Facebook Page Tab app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, tabs

As I am still new to FB App development I was wondering how to implement such Apps: https://www.facebook.com/Texterclub/app/1002447493202906/ and https://www.facebook.com/Minikinder.Lieblingssachen/app/511509218944445/

Basically these Apps display HTML content inside an iframe but according to the actual Page (shop, business etc) that has it embedded. I have already made a Page Tab App however in my scenario it should load different html contents based on the Page it is embedded.

Hence, does anyone have experience or have hints on how to implement such apps? Is it possible to **authenticate the user and based on his credentials** return a corresponding html content? After making the App live, in **which form will the user be able to install it**?

Comment: Actually in the other question, there is only a talk about getting page data. However, I need a way to authenticate the user with his credentials as to query my database for more infos...

Comment: Well go read the Facebook Login section of the documentation then.

Comment: (You are aware though, that Page Tabs are only available for pages, and not user profiles, right?)

Comment: Indeed i am aware of that fact. I decided I'd rely on the admin Page Tab Edit URL to have the user authenticate. One question that is still unanswered is how will the user install the Page Tab App once it's live.

Comment: Either via the dialog, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#adding, or via API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs#Creating